# C4D - Text to Cloth

Tags: text, 3d, cinema4d, simulation

### Having problems simulating Text on Cloth

Hope this is the right topic for this.

I want to simulate a peace of cloth with text on it waving in the wind, but with the flag itself being invisible. **Only the text is supposed to be rendered.**

I can't do it like in the attached picture and just use a black flag on flag background, because I need a natural lighted background. I also want shading on the text, and not like in the picture.

I can't even manage to attach text to the Plane with the cloth tag I made, because I tried it with mograph text, and it didn't simulate.

[image: example of similar effect but missing proper lighting]

Comment: Setup transparency in the material. That may be from the images alpha or from a mask. Even before the simulation the flag should only show the text.

Comment: Rendering several passes could work well? You could get one pass/setup to render the mask, then just render the flag material itself and composite in Photoshop or similar.